# Apex: map.Put() byVal instead of byRef?

Tags: java, dictionary, salesforce, apex

I'd like to know if there is a way to .put() an element into a map by value instead of by reference.

I have a map> and a loop that fills it, like so:

```
    Map<string,List<string>> result = new Map<string,List<string>>();
    List<string> temp = new list<string>();

    for(CustomObj__c i:customList){
        for(CustomObj__c j:customList2){
            if(j.id == i.id){
               temp.add(j.Contact__r.Owner.Id);
               temp.add(j.Contact__r.Id);
               result.put(i.Deal__r.id, temp);
               temp.clear();
               break;
            }                
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I clear the temp list. I then end up with a map that has keys, but null list values. Is it possible to .put() the lists by value (create a copy) in the map so it's unaffected by the call to temp.clear()?

Thank you all,

Zac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can modify your code like this.In this code I am creating a new instance for each map insert.

Map> result = new Map>();
    List temp;

```
for(CustomObj__c i:customList){
    for(CustomObj__c j:customList2){
        if(j.id == i.id){
           temp = new list<string>();
           temp.add(j.Contact__r.Owner.Id);
           temp.add(j.Contact__r.Id);
           result.put(i.Deal__r.id, temp);
           break;
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good call. This works too. Do you know what happens with garbage collection in this case? When the function returns the map, does the list in the map still reference these lists or are the temp lists trashed and the returned value is byVal?

Comment: As long as there are reference to that map the value of list will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Does map (result) still reference the temp lists when it's returned by the function?

Comment: java is pass by value so when we are putting a list object as value in a map in that case it's always the memory address of the list object which will be stored in the map. and when map.get will be called in that case the memory address of the list object will be returned. So it's always the same reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it this way

```
            if(j.id == i.id){
               List<string> temp = new list<string>();
               temp.add(j.Contact__r.Owner.Id);
               temp.add(j.Contact__r.Id);
               result.put(i.Deal__r.id, temp);
```